# How to test WCF wsHttpBinding endpoint along with certificate using SOAP UI tool?

Tags: wcf, soapui, x509certificate, wcf-wshttpbinding

I want to test my wcf service endpoint using SOAP UI tool which is built in wsHttpBinding along with x509certificate authentication. It supports for basicHttpBinding and working properly but giving an error for wsHttpBinding. Any help would be appreciated. I'm getting below error message in response.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</a:Action>
      <a:RelatesTo>uuid:81f1ec47-0bd4-4dd0-b958-648ee934be24</a:RelatesTo>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <s:Code>
            <s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
            <s:Subcode>
               <s:Value xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">a:InvalidSecurity</s:Value>
            </s:Subcode>
         </s:Code>
         <s:Reason>
            <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred when verifying security for the message.</s:Text>
         </s:Reason>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: What is the error it is giving? The more information you provide the better the chance someone can provide a solution.

Comment: @strickt01 I have updated the query with error message

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how to use the tool SoapUI, or are you asking how to write a WCF service? In either case, you need to provide [mcve] so that we can know what you did, what you expect, and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

We are capable of testing the WCF service in SOAPUI if WCF service is created by Wshttpbinding and the required client credential is a certificate.
Please refer to the reply I wrote several days ago.
[Test WCF with Mutual Certificate Authentication using SOAPUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57892724/test-wcf-with-mutual-certificate-authentication-using-soapui/57918522#57918522)
Merely based on the security error. I could not infer that the code design on the server-side. I would like that you could post more details of the security binding configured on the server-side and the client's credential type so that I could make an example.
Besides, here are some links, wish it is useful to you.
[WCF wsHttpBinding in SoapUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169871/wcf-wshttpbinding-in-soapui)
https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/sending-https-requests.html
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.